# Expansion of the logarithm near $0$

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, asymptotics

Let $a\in\Bbb R$ be a constant, and let $(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be a sequence of real numbers. How fast must $b_n$ converge to $e^{-n+a}$ to ensure that $n+\log b_n\rightarrow a$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$? For example, is the condition that $b_n=e^{-n+a}+o(e^{-n})$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see. If $b_n = e^{-n+a}+\varepsilon(n)$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} \varepsilon(n)=0$, we get
$$\begin{align}
\log b_n &= \log(e^{-n+a}+\varepsilon(n))
= \log(e^a\left(e^{-n}+e^{-a}\varepsilon(n)\right))
= a + \log(e^{-n}+e^{-a}\varepsilon(n))
\\
&= a - n + \log(1+e^{-a}e^n\varepsilon(n))
\end{align}$$
so
$$
n+\log b_n = a+\log(1+e^{-a}e^n\varepsilon(n))\tag{1}
$$
For this to converge to $a$, it is sufficient (and necessary) that 
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(1+e^{-a}e^n\varepsilon(n)) = 0$, which is equivalent to 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}e^n\varepsilon(n) = 0 \tag{2}
$$
So **yes**, having $\varepsilon(n) = o(e^n)$ *is* sufficient. It is also necessary.